# Wordpress Bootstrap Responsive Nav Menu - how to toggle top menu's href link using Bootstrap Navwalker

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

For eg, in my wordpress navigation menu setup, it is as follows.

- Home
- About Us

  - Who We Are?
  - What We Do?
- Services

  - Web Development
  - Web Design

On all these menus and submenus, I have setup page link for each one of them so the user can navigate them as they please.

But when I use the Bootstrap navwalker php plugin as discussed in this tutorial
http://www.pattonwebz.com/wordpress-custom/bootstrap-wordpress-responsive-menu/

the About Us and Services's links are disabled.  This is because these two have sub menus content inside them and somehow the plugin just disabled any top menus' links that has sub menus in them.  May I ask what needs to be done to restore the links on About Us and Service menus?  Are there any options I can toggle in this wp_nav_menu code below?

```
<?php 
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'menu'       => 'top_menu',
          'depth'      => 2,
          'container'  => false,
          'menu_class' => 'nav',
          'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
          'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
?>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for readin the tutorial on my website :D This issue is something that we've come across many times but Bootstrap has made the decision to make everything mobile friendly - including these drop down menus. Clickable drop-downs do not work well with touchscreen devices and as such they are disabled by default. Twittem (the navwalker creator) made the decision to only include default markup and behavior in the walker class so getting top level clickable items requires some edits to the actual walker class - but know that enabling it alienates touch screen users.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to modify this navwalker in such a way that it does what you want - namely to output the link as the `href` value and to allow you to click the link.

There's 2 issues to contend with here:

1. The navwalker used is not outputting the url to the `href` property (instead it outputs '#').
2. Bootstrap disables the link click behavior with `e.preventDefault` and replaces it with it's own function.

Making the navwalker output a url and stopping Bootstrap take over the click behaviour is just a case of modifying a few lines in the navwalker. I have a fork of the repo that contains a [modified version of the walker](https://github.com/pattonwebz/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/tree/clickable-top-level) that does that.

Stopping Bootstrap take over the click behaviour of the link has some implications. The dropdown menus are opened on click by the Bootstrap JS so if you remove that then the menus can't be opened any more. A quick fix is to make them appear on hover of the parent. Here's css that does that:

```
.menu-item-has-children:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Do note that there's a reason why menu items with dropdowns are disabled in the original version of the Navwalker (and not supported by Bootstrap core). Making the top level items clickable links means dropdowns need to appear on hover instead. Touchscreen users can't hover. If you anticipate anyone using a touchscreen then you should avoid making the menu items with dropdowns links and instead keep them as dropdown toggles only.

Disclosure: I wrote the article referenced in the question and I contribute code to original navwalker used.

Answer (score 0):

**try with this one:** (befor trying it you should create your navigation menu from wordpress admin panel, without that, it will not work.)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container_class' => 'menu-header',
        'theme_location' => 'primary',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s nav navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
        'walker' => new BS3_Walker_Nav_Menu,
    )); ?>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

and for submenus see [here](http://www.flynsarmy.com/2013/10/getting-bootstrap-3-navbar-working-with-wordpress-wp_nav_menu/)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Next question - are you using Bootstrap 2.3 or Bootstrap 3?  I'm currently using Bootstrap 2.3...

Comment: `Bootrap 3` but I think it will work with `2.3` also, but u need to confirm it by trying it.

Comment: Okay.  I tried that.  That didn't work.. Same problem as the first one.

Comment: I looked at the link.  Tried to follow it.  Still no change.  Couldn't get any different results.....  Did that work for you?

Comment: Okay. I followed the instructions again.  This time I got it to work! But the css bubble sub menu is not appearing under the parent menu.  It's on the far left of the web page.  And the top menus's links still don't work when clicking even though they're showing the correct links.

Comment: have u completed all the steps for implementing sub-menus including functions and all?

Comment: I did.  But I still couldn't get it right...  Maybe there's something wrong with some of the written code as I assumed some of the code were typos..  I will have to start over again.  And let you know if it does work or not.

Comment: Okay. I did all the steps again.  Still have the same css bubble sub menu problem. No change.

Comment: Nope it's running locally on my machine..  But I got everything confused because I originally looked at this source of help: http://www.flynsarmy.com/2013/10/getting-bootstrap-3-navbar-working-with-wordpress-wp_nav_menu/  But that didn't work well at all... So now I need to revert it back to how it was in the beginning again.

Comment: dear, u know its Bootstrap 3 and u already checked that it doesn't worked for u.

Comment: at least I gave it a go.  I didn't want to assume it doesn't work until it's proven it doesn't work.  And because I've already spent a lot of effort to use Bootstrap 2 on my volunteer project, I don't want to migrate to Bootstrap 3 at this point in time yet..